# Glucagen-like Peptide 1 (GLP-1): Is there food containing it or increases it's production?

Tags: diet, diabetes, insulin

Insulin therapy affects the GLP-1 level of patients. Is there some "natural" appearance of GLP-1 in food, or food which stimulates GLP-1 production?

(Background: In Diabetes Typ 2 medication with GLP-1 analogs is approved to loss weight, at Typ 1 there are less or no medications with this approach ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5569154/)). For Typ 1 it is more difficult, because the insulin therapy influence the "natural" system (i.e. GLP-1 and Amylin) of get weight and loss weight. So I ask myself, if there is some "diet" which can affect the GLP-1 level in a positive manner.

Additional: Same question with Amylin /Amylin analogs...)

Edit: I do not want to medicate myself. I am a Bioinformatics Programmer and want to understand my actual project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GLP-1](https://diabetes.diabetesjournals.org/content/51/suppl_3/S434) is a hormone secreted by intestinal lining cells, which increases insulin sensitivity and slows down gastric emptying, which both help to control blood glucose levels after meals.

There are diets that stimulate the secretion of GLP-1 from the gut. It's not that foods contain GLP-1, but some foods can stimulate its secretion.

In some studies, virgin [olive oil](https://nutritionandmetabolism.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12986-016-0153-3), which is typically a part of a [Mediterranean diet](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25407792), [sunflower oil](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12571662), [pistachios](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4310069/), [soluble fiber](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21115020), and [high-fiber grain products, nuts, avocados and eggs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5148911/) increased the secretion of GLP-1.

Is there any evidence that any of the mentioned foods help to control glucose levels in diabetes type 2? Well...

According to a 2017 meta analysis of cohort studies in [Nutrition and Diabetes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5436092/), there is an association between olive oil consumption and decreased risk of diabetes type 2.

High intake of [cereal fiber](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5883628/) may help to prevent diabetes type 2.

*[High](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2628696/)* intake of eggs (>7/week) is associated with *increased* risk of diabetes type 2.

It's not that including or excluding an individual food can help in diabetes; it's more about a diet as a whole: maintaining healthy weight, avoiding large meals and sugary drinks, eating whole grains...([niddk.nih.gov](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/diabetes/overview/diet-eating-physical-activity)).

Comment: GLP-1 is a natural thing to stop you eating too much. You see that most foods I mentioned (oil, eggs, pistachios..) are fatty foods, so there are certain fatty acids from the food that trigger the release of GLP-1. Fatty foods are calorie dense and once you've eaten so and so much of faty foods, the release of GLP-1 tries to convince you to stop eating. But that's to prevent eating too much. In your scenario, you would need to consume less calories than one needs for a period of time. There are various distraction techniques available that allow you to do this without suffering too much.

Comment: Your answer is perfect fine :) After I have read the source in my question, I imagine how difficult it would be, to fight the desire for food, if your metabolism do not support you with it. And I remembered some food, that are telltales about to reduce appetite and ask myself, if there is some connection between for example GLP-1 and this food. But I do not know were to ask, because cook.SE is not expert in chemistry/biology, so I ask here :)

Comment: Your thinking is also perfectly fine. I want to convince you that in real life things are SIMPLER than GLP-1. This is too much science, and in my answer I did not emphasize that route of thinking may not be very effective. So, to _decrease appetite_, one can try to avoid sugary foods and to include some high-fiber foods (whole-grain bread and such). If one needs to eat less he/she just needs to start to eat less. It's a decision, a bit of psychological/physical effort and not some sort of metabolic miracle.